# ¿Cómo indico que una variable es unicode en Python?

Tags: python, json, utf-8, python-2.x, unicode

En Python 2.6 estoy realizando un proceso en el que obtengo unos valores de una base de datos y los necesito codificados en UTF-8. El código es equivalente al siguiente:

```
import json

valor = "CERDE\u00c3\u0091A"     #valor se obtiene de una BD
dict = {"indice": valor}
s = json.dumps(dict)
o = json.loads(s)
print o['indice'].encode('utf-8')
```

y el resultado que me muestra es:

```
CERDE\u00c3\u0091A
```

Manualmente transformo valor en:

```
valor = u"CERDE\u00c3\u0091A"
```

De manera que sí que se realiza la transformación a utf-8.

Me gustaría saber si existe una forma automática de indicar que es unicode y poder transformar los datos. Según tengo entendido `str.decode()` genera un string UNICODE, dado que yo ya tengo un string UNICODE realizo el `encode('utf-8')` pero el resultado sigue siendo unicode.

Gracias,

Comment: No acabo de entender el porqué de _indicar que es unicode_. ¿Cuál es tu objetivo final con esta cadena? ¿Quieres pasarlo a unicode? Para saber qué es, usa `type(cadena)`. Para pasarlo de unicode a string, usa `str(cadena)`.

Comment: Cuando accedo a mis datos me retorna esto: CERDE\u00c3\u0091A, que no lo entiende como un unicode. Lo entiende un string, por lo tanto será un ISO o UTF8. Mi intención es poder identificar esto como un unicode, al igual que se hace manualmente introduciendo la u en u"CERDE\u00c3\u0091A"

Comment: Haz `print type(o['indice'])` y `print repr(o['indice'])` a ver que obtienes.

Comment: @FJSevilla he obtenido: <type 'str'> y "NOMBRE_INDICE": "CERDE\\u00c3\\u0091A, 350                                                "   por lo que veo a la hora de guardarlo se guardó el código Unicode como string, no?

Comment: Ufff, vale vamos a ir para atrás, haz lo mismo pero con el valor **nada más obtenido de la base de datos**, antes de crear el diccionario y el json:  `print type(valor)` y `print repr(valor)`. Estos problemas son simples pero un latazo de encontrar porque nosotros no podemos reproducirlos al carecer de la BD tal y como tu la tienes.

Comment: @FJSevilla el valor obtenido de la BD es el que he puesto (aparentemente algo parecido a un json/diccionario). El type de valor es str.  Por lo tanto, tengo un str que si hago repr observo que tiene doble contra barra (\\).

Ahora he llegado a la conclusión de que si remplazo las dos contra barras por una, deberia entender que \\u00c3\\u009 es un caracter unicode. Pero tampoco lo consigo hacer porque si hago: valor.remplace("\\","\") no puedo cerrar bien...

Comment: David: no, esa doble barra la añade `repr()` ([Why do backslashes appear twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24085680/1983854)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supongamos que tenemos una cadena de tipo `str` (o sea tipo `bytes` en Python 3)

```
>>> cad = "espa\u00F1ol"
```

Manualmente podemos construir una cadena unicode mediante:

```
>>> cad = u'espa\u00F1ol'
>>> print cad
español
```

Para hacer este mismo proceso usando una variable `str` de partida podemos usar `str.decode` de la siguiente forma:

```
>>> cad = "espa\u00F1ol"
>>> print type(valor)
<type 'str'>
>>> print cad
espa\u00F1ol
>>> cad_u = cad.decode('unicode-escape') #<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>> print type(cad_u)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print cad_u
español
```

Otra opción para hacer lo mismo es:

```
cad_u = unicode(cad, 'unicode-escape')
```

Dependiendo del módulo que uses para manejar la base de datos es posible que puedas modificar esto con anterioridad para que retorne una cadena de tipo unicode de partida.

---

Voy a intentar esponder a la razonable duda de @fedorqui planteada en el comentario en esta respuesta.

Vamos a partir de la premisa necesaria de que nuestra consola/intérprete/módulo python trabaja con codificación Unicode (si se trata de un módulo, usando `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`)

Partiendo de lo anterior, en Python 2 al construir una variable `str` no es lo mismo hacer:

```
cad = "1\u20ac es un euro"
```

que hacer:

```
cad = '1€ es un euro'
```

`str` no es más que una colección de bytes que son interpretados como caracteres ASCII si es posible. Se corresponde con el tipo `bytes` de Python 3. En Python 3, en cambio, `str` almacena texto (bytes + codificación) UTF-8.

Cuando introducimos `1\u20ac es un euro`, al estar trabajando en unicode en nuestro archivo/intérprete interactivo la representación real (lo que veríamos si miraramos el raw de nuestro .py) sería (representando cada byte en hexadecimal):

> 31**e282ac**20657320756e206575726f

en cambio con `1\u20ac es un euro` lo que el intérprete lee es algo como:

> 31**5c7532306163**20657320756e206575726f

El problema viene a la hora de construir una variable `str` y cómo Python almacena internamente esto. Como `str` es un array de bytes y nada más, almacena **literalmente** los bytes que se le pasan entre las comillas. Eso sí, las secuencias de escape que tienen equivalencia ASCII como son `\n`, `\r`, `\t` son correctamente interpretadas pero este no es el caso de '\u'. Al no ser reconocida, se escapa '\' para que sea tratado como un carácter más, como podemos ver con `repr`:

```
>>> print repr('\n')
'\n'
>>> print repr('€')
'\x80'
>>> print repr('\u20ac')
'\\u20ac'
```

Vemos como en el caso de `\n` no se escapa "\" en la representación interna del objeto `str`. En el caso de `\u` sí que se escapa.

En el caso de la pregunta parece que lo que le retorna la base de datos es una cadena de la forma:

```
"1\u20ac es un euro"
```

lo que equivale a decir que le retorna un array de bytes como:

```
\0x31\0x5c\0x75\0x32\0x30\0x61\0x63\0x20\0x65\0x73\0x20\0x75\0x6e\0x20\0x65\0x75\0x72\0x6f
```

y lo que quiere es codificar eso a un texto unicode como si hiciera:

```
cad = u"1\u20ac es un euro"
```

Podríamos pensar que aplicando `cad.decode('UTF-8')` obtendríamos lo que queremos, pero no es así ya que la cadena es representada internamente como `"1\\u20ac es un euro"`. Necesitamos especificarle que la secuencia de escape hace referencia a un cáracter unicode y ahí es donde entra [`str.decode('unicode-escape')`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
>>> cad ='1\u20ac es un euro'
>>> cad = cad.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> print repr(cad)
u'1\u20ac es un euro'
>>>> print(cad)
1€ es un euro
```

Realmente el manejo de cadenas en Python 2.x es para mi una  negra del lenguaje. No es nada intuitivo en muchos aspectos y lleva a problemas de codificación absurdos en muchas veces. Este aspecto es mucho más congruente en Python 3 con la redefinición de los tipos bytes y str junto a otros aspectos como el uso de UTF-8 en el código por defecto. De hecho el problema que plantea el OP no se daría en Python 3:

- **Python 2.x:**

  ```
  >>> cad ='1\u20ac es un euro'
  >>> print cad
  1\u20ac es un euro
  ```
- **Python 3.x:**

  ```
  >>> cad ='1\u20ac es un euro'
  >>> print(cad)
  1€ es un euro
  ```

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla! Después si que puedo codificar sin problemas a UTF-8!

Comment: Solo por aprender: ¿cuál es la diferencia con respecto a lo que yo propuse?

Comment: @fedorqui he editado la respuesta intentado responder a tu duda, digo "he intentado" porque no se si habré conseguido algo, a veces explicar lo que me parece simple se me da fatal :)

Comment: Fantástico, FJSevilla, muchísimas gracias por la explicación. El tema de la codificación siempre me genera dolores de cabeza y creo que aquí he visto un poco de luz finalmente :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Solución fácil

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Es importante que este en la primera línea de código, entonces obtendrás directamente el resultado deseado.

Solo meter este **import** en el caso de generar el String. Si lo envías por parámetro será un String normal i no funcionara.

Creo que es delicado, porque donde deberás poner esta cabezalera será donde haces **import**. I puede que deje de compilar con esta nueva línea.

```
value = "CERDE\u00c3\u0091A" # provenga de quien tenga el import
```

## Mala solución

```
valor = "CERDE\u00c3\u0091A"
valor = valor.replace ("\u00c3", u"\u00c3")
valor = valor.replace ("\u0091", u"\u0091")
```

I obtendras la salida deseada

## Cambiar

Debido a estos tipos de problemas, python2 se transformo en python3.
En python3 no tendrás este problema.
Lo hace automáticamente.

Comment: Gracias! Lo tendré en cuenta porque las codificaciones me están volviendo loco...

Comment: @DavidNavarro efectivamente `from __future__ import unicode_literals ` hace que las cadenas sean tratadas como se hace en Python 3, son cadenas UTF-8 por defecto si son creadas dentro del módulo donde se produce el import. Si no tienes ningún impedimento de fureza mayor por incopatibilidad de módulos/sistema pasate a Python 3 como te recomienda, el manejo de cadenas en Python 2.x es poco pythónico para mi gusto y termina desesperando a veces si te ves oblidado a trabajar con algo que no sea inglés...

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Escribo una respuesta para que nos entendamos mejor. En los comentarios se hace complicado.</sup>

Supongamos que creas una cadena de esta forma:

```
>>> s = '1€ es un euro'
>>> s
'1\xe2\x82\xac es un euro'
>>> type(s)
str
```

Como ves, contiene caracteres del tipo `\xe` para designar algo *raro* como es el símbolo de euro *€*. Esta variable es de tipo string.

Decidimos convertirla a Unicode, utilizando la función `decode()` que tú mencionas. Lo hacemos designando la salida de `decode()` a otra variable, puesto que es una función que devuelve un valor, no cambia el valor de la variable sobre la que se aplica:

```
>>> en_unicode = s.decode('utf-8')
>>> en_unicode
u'1\u20ac es un euro'
>>> type(en_unicode)
unicode
```

`type()` nos indica el tipo de la variable, que es Unicode.

Vale, y ahora supongamos que queremos volver a la cadena original. Pues con `.encode()` lo tenemos:

```
>>> en_unicode.encode('utf-8')
'1\xe2\x82\xac es un euro'
>>> type(en_unicode.encode('utf-8'))
str
```